# RAM fails across all DIMMS on the same 1 or 2 bits

Tags: memory, memtest86+

Computer: Dell Precision T5400
Memory: 16 Gb (2Gb x 8) 667 Mhz PC2-5300F ECC Fully Buffered

The computer ran fine for years, then reported a "single bit error" the other day, followed by blue screens.  Every time I managed to fix a software problem, another one popped up.  Eventually, I suspected hardware.

In the below Memtest86+ tests, I'm running 6 of the 8 DIMMS, 12 Gb, because 1 appears faulty right off the bat when plugged in and the machine refuses to start with it, and it also won't run with some pairs and others as singles, so I took out the suspected faulty one and another one to keep the number of modules even.

On the remaining modules, I get errors in the same 2 bit positions across all portions of memory - always the last 2 bits.  I don't see how the computer could have run so well for so long, then all of a sudden had all the memory modules fail together, unless the ECC somehow kept that well hidden, or - is this likely a bad memory controller or other motherboard issue?

Thanks for any help.  Apparently I am not allowed to embed images, so sorry, these are a bunch of links.

[Example - close up - notice last 2 bits of "Err-Bits" column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6J2u.jpg)

[Example: 2040-3052 MB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6x6AL.jpg)

[Example: 4096-6144 MB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxPzV.jpg)

[Example: 6144 - 8192 MB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfBAd.jpg)

[Last 512 MB of 12G](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKnyc.jpg)

Comment: It appears you have more than 2 bad modules.  Have you recently by chance reinstalled the processor?

Comment: No, I haven't touched the processor before.

Comment: Actually the most stupid thing I ever did was to add a pair of DIMM modules a friend had donated to me. They seemed to run OK for some time, but suddenly I had mysterious crashes and massive file system corruption. As you discovered, there was not a single bit bad, but a whole "column". So do what I did: Dump those modules. Of course it could be a contact problem (maybe re-seat the modules) or a problem outside of the RAM modules. Still the best way to find out is replacing those modules.

Comment: On the images: You could down-size them a bit, maybe even clearing them up and fixing the distortion, and then you should be able to present them inline.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  I'm now removing the bulk of them and testing them in smaller groups to see if perhaps 1 or 2 are causing a failure on the bus that's making them all appear bad.  On the images, believe it or not I actually did compress them after I took them.  How do you place them inline, or is that something the site would have offered had I made them small enough?

Comment: After overnight testing, 2 pairs each passed separately, but it appears Memtest86+ is running them at half speed (332 MHz vs 667), so I'm guessing one needs to stuff all the slots to operate at full speed?

Answer (score -1):

You would need to look into a new motherboard.